# Como seleccionar una fila de una tabla en html

Tags: javascript, html, html-tabla

Hola tengo que hacer un ejercicio donde:

Al hacer doble click en una fila de la grilla debe mostrarse, en el centro de la página,
una sección donde debe autocompletarse los datos de la persona. Contendrá un texto
para el nombre, un texto para poner el apellido, un radio para el sexo y un date para la
fecha, un botón para Modificar y un botón Eliminar. (El id no debe mostrase al usuario)

cuando se haga doble click se me abrira un contenedor con los datos de la fila escogida, pero no se como hacer para si quiera crear un evento y se me abra el contenedor que ya tengo echo. nunca vimos jsquery. asi que no se como deberia hacerla

```
function DobleClick()
{
  const tds=document.querySelectorAll("td");
  for(td of tds)
  {
      td.addEventListener("dblclick",function() 
      {
        AbrirContenedor();
        var btnModificar=document.getElementById("btnModificar");
        btnModificar.addEventListener("click",GuardarClick);
        var btnCerrar=document.getElementById("btnCerrar");
        var btnEliminar=document.getElementById("btnEliminar");
        btnEliminar.addEventListener("click",CerrarContenedor);
        btnCerrar.addEventListener("click", CerrarContenedor);
      }); 
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: Intentastes investigar como hacerlo? O pon lo que hicistes hasta ahora

Comment: const tds=document.querySelectorAll("td");
  for(td of tds)
  {
      td.addEventListener("dblclick",function() 
      {
        AbrirContenedor();
        var btnModificar=document.getElementById("btnModificar");
        btnModificar.addEventListener("click",GuardarClick);
        var btnCerrar=document.getElementById("btnCerrar");
        var btnEliminar=document.getElementById("btnEliminar");
        btnEliminar.addEventListener("click",CerrarContenedor);
        btnCerrar.addEventListener("click", CerrarContenedor);
      }); 
  } No me funciona

Comment: En tu pregunta, para que se entienda mejor. Lea [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para futuras preguntas

Comment: Intente de esa manera pero no me funciona porque mi tabla la cargue a partir de un archivo json. y No se que tiene que ver pero bueno no funciona cuando pongo td, pero cuando pongo tr si pero le haria doble click a las columnas y no es lo que necesito

Comment: Ahora si peudes ver mejor